# Can I force "nla: bake action" to bake every frame?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I'm trying to get the Bake Action, to put a keyframe in every frame or every two frames or whatever no matter what, seems like if the value is the same it wont, but I want a keyframe in every frame
is there a way to force this behavior?